# New to react, page/html not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When I run my node server how come nothing shows on the html page? I am new to react and I am learning from Code Academy. From what I have been learning, I am doing the exact same thing I am being taught. The login box is not showing at all.

Login.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form id="Login" className="form-signin" action="/login" method="POST">
        <h2 className="form-signin-heading">Sign in</h2>
        <input className="form-control" type="text" id="user" name="user" />
        <label className="sr-only" for="user" />
        <input className="form-control" type="password" id="pass" name="pass" />
        <label className="sr-only" for="pass" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button> <br />
      </form>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Login />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

login.html

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Signin</title>

  <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--React Libraries -->
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <!--React called here  -->
  <div id="app" class="container">

  </div>

  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/login.js" type="text/babel"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined is shown on the browser console as well

Comment: is this all the code your using? I feel like there might be more?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the import statements from your login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

They are not needed if you are going to run UMD version of react.

You can also rename `login.js` to `login.jsx` since its not normal js.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use "for" HTML attribute in javascript since its a reserved keyword used to iterate. 
You should use "htmlFor"

```
<label className="sr-only" htmlFor="user"></label>
```

I've created a pen, follow the link below

https://codepen.io/sunilrana/pen/RJKVVG